# Econtainer null when loading EMF containment from Database using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, emf

I have an EMF containment hierarchy: An **House** contains a list of **Room**s, represented using an ecore file.

Before persisting, when I initially create my house and populate it with rooms, the *eContainer* value for a *Room* object correctly show the containing house. I then use Hibernate (no Teneo involved) to save the house (which cascade-saves the rooms).

When I reload the House object, I get references to all the Rooms. However, the *eContainer* value for a Room is now *null*. This is relevant because I use *EcoreUtil.delete(bathroom)* to delete a Room from its containing house, and that uses *EObject.eContainer()*.

Relevant Hibernate Mapping:

```
 <class name="House" table="house" lazy="false">
 <bag name="rooms" lazy="true" cascade="save-update, delete">
        <key update="true">
            <column name="house_id" unique="false"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Room"/>
 </bag>
 </class>
 <class name="Room" table="room" lazy="false">
 </class>
```

What should I do to delete EMF objects? Should I call something other than EcoreUtil.delete(obj)? Should I manually add the eContainer references on load? Should I change my hibernate mapping?

Comment: What is the reason for not using Teneo? It is the bridge between EMF and Hibernate...

Comment: The main reason (perhaps not a good one) is we have been using Hibernate since the beginning, and don't know how hard it would be to migrate over to Teneo.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate requires every property to have a getter and setter. In EMF (not using Teneo at least), there is a getter for *Rooms* but no setter.

```
public EList<Room> getRooms() {
    if (rooms == null) {
        rooms = new EObjectContainmentEList<Room>(Room.class, this, housePackage.HOUSE__ROOM);
    }
    return rooms;
}
```

I provided my own setter below.

```
public void setRooms(List<Room> roomList) {
    this.rooms = new BasicEList<>();
    this.rooms.addAll(roomList);
}
```

This was incorrect because a *BasicEList* does not do any provide EMF notification, so the *eContainer* was not getting set. I changed to the following, which in the underlying implementation uses a *EObjectContainmentEList* and so far it seems to work.

```
public void setRooms(List<Room> roomList) {
    ECollections.setEList(getRooms(), roomList);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to ask on the Teneo (EMF Technology) forum for a migration strategy before trying to build your own bridge. The author is quite responsive. I am sure this is not the only trap you have fallen into...